# Slicing Numpy Array by Array of Indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am attempting to slice a Numpy array by an array of indices. For example,

```
 array = [10,15,20,25,32,66]
 indices = [1,4,5]
```

The optimal output would be

```
[[10][15,20,25,32][66]]
```

I have tried using

```
 array[indices]
```

but this just produces the single values of each individual index rather than all those in between.

Comment: What exactly do your three indices in the array represent. I do not really understand how you get to your desired output from the given input.

Comment: The indices are obtained by np.where(). So basically the indices, 1,4,5, would slice the array like so: 0:1, 1:4, 4:5

Comment: What you call "optimal output" cannot be the product of a slicing operation, because it has an undefined shape.

Comment: @TrevorJudice Then why is the last output result 66 and not 32?

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest is correct. What you could get is a list containing the slices that you wanted to have. Also as Mitch was saying the last element of your desired output does not match your way of constructing it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html), like so

```
array = np.asarray([10, 15, 20, 25, 32, 66])
indices = [1, 5]

print(np.split(array, indices))
```

Produces

```
[array([10]), array([15, 20, 25, 32]), array([66])]
```

As `split` uses breakpoints only, where the index indicates the points at which to break blocks. Hence, no need to indicate `1:4`, this is implicitly defined by breakpoints `1, 5`.

Comment: What a useful little function this `np.split`! If only it could do multiple axes.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005980/slicing-numpy-array-by-array-of-indices/42006223#comment71188147_42005980) this generator produces the desired result:

```
def slice_multi(array, indices):
    current = 0
    for index in indices:
        yield array[current:index]
        current = index

array = [10,15,20,25,32,66]
indices = [1,4,5]
list(slice(array, indices)) # [[10], [15, 20, 25], [32]]
```

Comment: It does when you take his comment into account where he states, that the last slice should be `array[4:5]` which is indeed `[32]`.

Comment: This produces the result of slicing `[0:1], [1:4], [4:5]`, as stated in the comment. I just produced the solution which fit the comment, since it's different from the one stated in the original question.

Comment: `numpy.split(array, indices)[-1]` is probably easier, though.

Comment: But that's exactly what `np.array_slice` does - iteratively slice along the desired axis and return a list of arrays.  Look at it's code. It's not compiled.